# Meaning of explicitly and implicitly parameterized probability distributions

Tags: distributions, bayesian

In [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_lower_bound#Variational_Bayesian_inference) it states:

> Since there are not many **explicitly** parametrized distribution families (all the classical distribution families, such as the normal distribution, the Gumbel distribution, etc, are far too simplistic to model the true distribution), we consider **implicitly** parametrized probability distributions: ...

My question is -- what exactly is meant here by **explicitly** and **implicitly** parameterized probability distributions? Does 'explicitly' mean that we know what the functions are that generated the parameters (e.g., in a normal distribution I would have a function for the mean that is based on some latent random variable $z$ , such as: $\mu(z) = z^2$)?

Comment: I have to admit, I found reading that article difficult (despite a PhD with a thesis on a Bayesian statistics topic). The particular terminology comes from [an edit in 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Evidence_lower_bound&diff=prev&oldid=1099156177), so perhaps an option to contact that author and/or for people to jump in and make the article more accessible in terms of language/terminology?